# Performance of local AppEngine 1.7.3 dev server for UI tests

Tags: google-app-engine

We recently upgraded from AppEngine (Java) 1.6.3 to 1.7.3. We have a large suite of UI tests that run in a CI environment against the local dev server (launched via Ant).

Before the upgrade, the UI tests would take about 4 hours to run each night. Since the upgrade, they take 9 to 10 hours. I did a downgrade to double-check something else wasn't at play and the build took the usual 4-ish hours again.

Is there anything in the intervening releases that might have caused this? I'm about to go release by release to try to pinpoint things further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good chance your code is spending a lot of time in CheckRestricted methods.  You could profile it to find out for sure if that is really the case.  Check this issue for more info:

Java Dev Server Extremely Slow in 1.6.4
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7282

Comment: That very well may be. We do a lot of data setup and teardown in the UI tests. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: On further investigation, it does look like an issue with the data setup/teardown. But the problem gets worse as time goes on. At the beginning of the tests, the setup takes about the same time as it used to. As they progress, it takes longer and longer. This kind of suggests a memory leak somewhere, doesn't it?

Comment: Have you tried to profile with something like VisualVM?  That should give you more visibility as to what's happening and the cause.  I've read also the SDK datastore implementation is not suited to large datasets, so maybe that is also relevant if you start to get a lot of data entries as tests progress.